# In PHP, why is the string "1874S-O.jpg" not greater than "1874S.jpg"?

Tags: php, sorting

I was attempting to sort some strings in an array alphabetically. The strings were file names I grabbed from a directory using glob. At first, I thought glob was incorrectly sorting the file names. I tried sort, and the same thing happened: `1874S-O.jpg` came before `1874S.jpg`

Finally, I compared them with

```
var_dump("11-09-2016/1874S/1874S-O.jpg" > "11-09-2016/1874S/1874S.jpg");
```

which returned `bool(false)`. Any ideas why the longer string would not be greater than the shorter string and would also not come after the shorter string alphabetically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `.` is greater than `-`.

Those are the first non-equal characters in your strings.

Comment: Do you mean that PHP does not add up the values of all the characters and compare them but instead determines whether one string is greater than the other by looking at the first character that's different?

Comment: @DavidRichied: Adding up values would make no sense (try `ABQ` vs. `BB`).  It compares each character, like standard alphabetical comparison.

Comment: You're right. I did not think through that question at all.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is sorting this by [ASCII decimal value](http://www.asciitable.com/). The sorting compares until it finds unequal values.

`.` has a value of 46

`-` has a value of 45

For kicks, you can check out [this demo](https://3v4l.org/CUoNm), where `%` is also less than `.`